# Import Data from Excel into SQL local server group ( SQL Native client 10.0)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have been breaking my head over importing excel file into SQL local server using a query.

I use the import/export wizard with source as Excel and destination as SQL native server client 10.0.

But i need an automated process for importing multiple Excel files into sql.

Following is the code I have been trying but it says

> server not Registered.

```
USE [master]
GO
--ADD DRIVERS IN SQL INSTANCE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'IN2232315W2\SQLEXPRESS2014',   
N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'IN2232315W2\SQLEXPRESS2014', 
N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO

 SELECT * INTO SU
 FROM OPENROWSET('IN2232315W2\SQLEXPRESS2014',
   'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\challa.sriharsha\Desktop\FINAL - VIRTUSA - SOD\SU\SU.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [SU$]');
```

Comment: What edition of SQL Server? in anything other than Express, you can use SSIS to do this in an automatic fashion

Comment: Sql server 12.0.5207

Comment: If you want an automated process, investigate SSIS

Comment: IN2232315W2\SQLEXPRESS2014 is not a valid provider name, it seems to be sql server instance name, so it's not clear what you want to achieve by executing EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'IN2232315W2\SQLEXPRESS2014',   
N'AllowInProcess', 1